# What would you call a "sheath" for a spherical object?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was looking for a word to describe a sort of cloth sheath you could use to store a [boule de pétanque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Boule.kugel.jpg). I found myself in the strange position of knowing the appropriate word in French ([*housse*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/housse#French)) and in Spanish (*[funda](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/housse#Spanish)*) but not in my native language. Both these words basically mean a *covering*. Those are the words used in their respective languages for a (hard or soft) guitar case for example.

I was imagining a kind of form-fitting sock that the *boule* could be put in. 
The image I have in mind is something like the socks sold as protective covers for mobile phones:

[image]

What would that be called in English? I tried dictionary translation but got things like *sheath*, *slipcover* and *dust cover*. *Sheath* does not work on a sphere and the other two don't work for me in this context either (please let me know if you disagree).

The best I could come up with is a *jacket* but again, not as general as *case*. Basically I am looking for a word that would describe a form fitting, soft protective cover without implying hardness (*case*), a particular shape (*sheath*) or a specific use (*dust cover* makes me think of machinery and *slipcover* of furniture).

---

EDIT: I just thought of *sleeve* as in *record sleeve* but I am not sure that I've ever heard it used outside the context of records or CDs or disks in general. That's the type of thing I am looking for though, something that is used more to protect than to transport.

---

<sup>If you believe that one of the words I have mentioned is the best fit, please let me know. I feel they are not suited but am quite willing to accept I'm wrong on this one.</sup>

Comment: "Protector" is a fairly common term for a form-fitting padded or armoured container designed specifically to protect its contents.

Comment: @user867 good point. That would be something to fall back on at least, that would be easily understood. Thanks.

Comment: "slipcover" is very good. Although it is usually associated with upholstery, there is very little chance of being misunderstood. It is a fitted cover which conforms to the shape of the object.

Comment: Why do you need an English word to denote the jacket (another of your above words that is good, by the way) surrounding something called a "boule de pétanque".

Comment: @Kaz because I was speaking English at the time and was intrigued to find I did not know what to call it. It just struck me as strange that I could think of the generic term for it in two languages I learned as an adult and not in one I grew up speaking.

Comment: _Sleeve_ is indeed used for things like beer can insulators, at least in the United States. Run a Google search for _beer sleeve_ for examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think perhaps the term [cosy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cosy) is appropriate.  A quick Google search reveals a number of items similar to your picture which are being marketed as a ["phone cosy"](https://www.google.com/search?es_sm=122&biw=1066&bih=558&tbm=shop&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22phone+cosy%22&oq=%22phone+cosy%22&gs_l=serp.3...5879.9627.2.10289.4.3.1.0.0.0.177.464.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.31.psy-ab..4.0.0.pWKMRS_9bv4&pbx=1)

For example, a red knit Phone Cosy.

[image]

Another application of the term cosy is a [tea cosy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tea+cozy.)

Seems to me you might be looking at a ball cosy, although it is more of a neologism than a defined word.

Comment: Like a "tea cosy", nice one!

Comment: You read my mind @terdon I was updating my answer with a tea cosy reference while you were commenting.  :)

Comment: I think it would be understood it if it came with some context: _Marge knit a nice cosy for Homer's new bowling ball_.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this usage is a little bit whimsical and operates by analogy to an *egg cosy* which is a (usually knitted) cover to keep a boiled egg warm in the egg cup. I assume the temperature of the *boule de pétanque* is not so important.

Comment: The purpose of a cosy is to keep the thing it is holding warm, so this doesn't seem quite right, although it could work.

Answer (score 17):

I immediately thought of a [*pouch*:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pouch)

> *noun* -- a small bag or other flexible receptacle, typically carried in a pocket or attached to a belt
>
> *a tobacco pouch*

[image]

Comment: Ah, yes, pouch is good, +1! Again though, as the definition states, a pouch is for carrying not for protection (though it can be used for both obviously).

Answer (score 7):

The term **bag** is used in US English for a wide variety of containers

> a flexible container with an opening at one end

It also is routinely used to mean luggage and as part of the terms for  specialized containers such as

- gym bag
- garbage bag
- feed bag
- punching bag
- goody bag
- laundry bag
- air sickness bag
- lunch bag

While these terms are not limited to spherical forms, they are often used to hold such objects.

An alternative is *sack*.

Comment: Yes, _bag_ did occur to me but that brings to (my) mind something designed for carrying objects rather than protecting them and is usually not form-fitting. I freely admit I may be asking for too much here though :). Also, I would avoid using _sack_ for something that holds what is essentially a _ball_. I would run the risk of being misunderstood: _Pass me my ball sack would'ya_?

Comment: There are *bags* so named for related equipment, such as *bocce ball bags* like [these](http://www.amazon.com/Playaboule-Extra-Heavy-Duty-Bocce/dp/B004WLIAPK), although I might avoid *ball bag* for the reasons you suggest.

Comment: And the possessive is even worse (ball's). Joking apart though, that bag is not really what I want. As you can see in the picture you posted, it is designed more to carry than to protect and is, well a _bag_, so not form-fitting. Hmm, I just thought of _sleeve_, that might work.

Comment: @terdon Bags can be protective, and can also be form fitting. Drum bags fit tightly over the drum inside so that the drum does not shift or move, and are designed to protect both the shell and the head from damage. See the link to amazon in [my answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/278312/70061).

Comment: @terdon And a [bowling ball bag](http://contentinjection.com/bowling-ball-bags/) is roughly spherical and form fitting (some more than others).

Comment: @bib I'm not disputing that. However, for me, _bag_ lacks the implication of form fitting that is suggested by words like _sheath_ or _cosy_.

Answer (score 4):

If the purpose is protection, then I would go with 'case' or 'cover', although 
'bag' works as well.

'Case' could imply a hard object, whereas 'bag' implies a soft one. Either way, it's a 'cover'.

Something somewhat similar that occurs to me as a drummer: [drum cases, covers, and bags](http://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=11966841)

Comment: Answering here so we don't spam bib. Yes, could work in some contexts (so, +1) but doesn't seem to fit for me here. As a guitarist, not a drummer, _bag_ conjures up far more flimsy things than what I was looking for. I certainly wouldn't put my guitar in a bag! I'm sure it is used as you describe, it just doesn't sound right to my ear.

Answer (score 3):

A form-fitting protective container for an object is sometimes called a shell, which ideally captures the notion of a protective covering for a round object. It usually implies a hard material, but it can be used to refer to an article of clothing intended to be the outermost layer, for protection from weather or moisture.